# SQL - Subtracting a depleting value from rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a situation where I need to take a "quantity consumed" from one table, and apply it against a second table that has 1 or more rows that are "pooled lots" of quantities.  I'm not sure how to describe it better, here's what I mean from a table perspective:

```
Table Pooled_Lots
----------------------------
Id  Pool    Lot Quantity
1   1       1   5
2   1       2   10
3   1       3   4
4   2       1   7
5   3       1   1
6   3       2   5

Table Pool_Consumption
----------------------------
Id  PoolId  QuantityConsumed
1   1       17
2   2       8
3   3       10
```

I need a resulting rowset from a SQL query that would look like:

```
Pool    Lot Quantity    QuantityConsumed    RunningQuantity RemainingDemand SurplusOrDeficit
1       1   5           17                  0               12              NULL
1       2   10          17                  0               2               NULL
1       3   4           17                  2               0               2
2       1   7           8                   0               1               -1
3       1   1           10                  0               9               NULL
3       2   5           10                  0               4               -4
```

So, Pool_Consumption.QuantityConsumed needs to be a "depleting value" subtracted over the rows from Pooled_Lots where Pool_Consumption.PoolId = Pooled_Lots.Pool.  I can't figure out how you would state a query that says:

- If not on the last row, AmtConsumedFromLot = Quantity - QuantityConsumed if QuantityConsumed < Quantity, else Quantity
- If more rows, QuantityConsumed = QuantityConsumed - Quantity
- Loop until last row
- If last row, AmtConsumedFromLot = QuantityConsumed

Assume Id is a primary key, and the target DB is SQL 2005.

Edit:  Since people are proclaiming I am "not giving enough information, please close this"  Here is more:  There is *NO* set lot that the Pool_Consumption draws from, it needs to draw from *all* lots where Pool_Consumption.PoolId = Pooled_Lots.Pool, until QuantityConsumed is either completely depleted or I am subtracting against the last subset of Pooled_Lots rows where Pool_Consumption.PoolId = Pooled_Lots.Pool

I don't know how more to explain this.  This is not a homework question, this is not a made-up "thought exercise".  I need help trying to figure out how to properly subtract QuantityConsumed against multiple rows!

Comment: I don't know why people are up-voting this question, you have some serious data granularity issues.  The `Pool_Consumption` table doesn't specify what lot the consumed units come from.  Also, I fixed a typo. -1

Comment: Nevermind, I'm not going to bother fixing all your typos.  At the very least, spend a little more time getting the data straight on this question!  However, your design is flawed to begin with. (voted to close)

Comment: @JohnB This is what I am currently faced with, simplified as much as I can and without disclosing confidential data from my job.  Instead of being arrogant and proclaiming I am asking a stupid question unworthy of votes, perhaps you can enlighten me as to where I need to add "granularity" to get myself to a point where I can produce the desired output more easily?

Comment: What typos?  I don't see any, if you corrected 1 I don't see any more.  I have also updated the question to indicate that there is no granularity issue, I need this subtraction to happen against *all* lots in a given pool.

Comment: It's not arrogance, please read my first comment if you didn't already (you need Lot # in `Pool_Consumption` table).  Also, I down-voted you because of the quality of the question, too many typos (makes it harder to read).

Comment: You keep saying I need a lot # in pool_consumption.  Why?  The QuantityConsumed is against *all* lots in a pool, not one particular lot in a pool.

Comment: Edited to fix problems in question and removed down vote.

Comment: I was one of the +1's. I agree that @John's tone came across as overly harsh.  This question is well formed the OP took time explaining the scenario, and asks a valid SQL question.  Fair enough that having `Lot` added to `Pool_Consumption` would be useful.  I can, however, conceive of scenarios where tying consumption to specific lots is unnecessary or even unknown (and therefore inaccurate to record).  The business rule seems to be deplete pools with the lowest PoolID first, then cascade up.

Comment: @/Irinotecan does your output query require Lot (as in V2 of this post)? Or can Lot be dropped as in @JohnB's V4 edit?

Comment: Sorry I came across as harsh.  I guess I got upset because the math was off, however, in spite of that I still understood the point of your question.  Furthermore, the original format of your desired result set threw me off because it was impossible to achieve based on your `Pool_Consumption` schema.  We spent 30 min fixing your question instead of working out the solution. :(

Comment: It does require lot, but if that's impossible I am open to making changes.  The biggest constraint here is that I don't know the lots to consume from ahead of time, just the total amount from the pool over all the lots.

Comment: Then I would suggest you roll back the question to V3 as John's edits are inaccurate.  Also, we need some rule to know how to consume lots. Can we consume lots with the lowest ID first (as in your V3 example)?

Comment: user92546's answer is giving me the results I am looking for, I'll revert the table to make it accurate.  Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Left as an exercise to the OP: Figuring out the correct results given the sample data and summarizing the results of the following query:

```
-- Create some test data.
declare @Pooled_Lots as table ( Id int, Pool int, Lot int, Quantity int );
insert into @Pooled_Lots ( Id, Pool, Lot, Quantity ) values
  ( 1, 1, 1, 5 ), ( 2, 1, 2, 10 ), ( 3, 1, 3, 4 ),
  ( 4, 2, 1, 7 ),
  ( 5, 3, 1, 1 ), ( 6, 3, 2, 5 );
declare @Pool_Consumption as table ( Id int, Pool int, QuantityConsumed int );
insert into @Pool_Consumption ( Id, Pool, QuantityConsumed ) values
  ( 1, 1, 17 ), ( 2, 2, 8 ), ( 3, 3, 10 );

select * from @Pooled_Lots order by Pool, Lot;
select * from @Pool_Consumption order by Pool;

with Amos as (
  -- Start with Lot 1 for each Pool.
  select PL.Pool, PL.Lot, PL.Quantity, PC.QuantityConsumed,
    case
      when PC.QuantityConsumed is NULL then PL.Quantity
      when PL.Quantity >= PC.QuantityConsumed then PL.Quantity - PC.QuantityConsumed
      when PL.Quantity < PC.QuantityConsumed then 0
      end as RunningQuantity,
    case
      when PC.QuantityConsumed is NULL then 0
      when PL.Quantity >= PC.QuantityConsumed then 0
      when PL.Quantity < PC.QuantityConsumed then PC.QuantityConsumed - PL.Quantity
      end as RemainingDemand
    from @Pooled_Lots as PL left outer join
      @Pool_Consumption as PC on PC.Pool = PL.Pool
    where Lot = 1
  union all
  -- Add the next Lot for each Pool.
  select PL.Pool, PL.Lot, PL.Quantity, CTE.QuantityConsumed,
    case
      when CTE.RunningQuantity + PL.Quantity >= CTE.RemainingDemand then CTE.RunningQuantity + PL.Quantity - CTE.RemainingDemand
      when CTE.RunningQuantity + PL.Quantity < CTE.RemainingDemand then 0
      end,
    case
      when CTE.RunningQuantity + PL.Quantity >= CTE.RemainingDemand then 0
      when CTE.RunningQuantity + PL.Quantity < CTE.RemainingDemand then CTE.RemainingDemand - CTE.RunningQuantity - PL.Quantity
      end
    from Amos as CTE inner join
      @Pooled_Lots as PL on PL.Pool = CTE.Pool and PL.Lot = CTE.Lot + 1
  )
select *,
  case
    when Lot = ( select max( Lot ) from @Pooled_Lots where Pool = Amos.Pool ) then RunningQuantity - RemainingDemand
    else NULL end as SurplusOrDeficit
  from Amos
  order by Pool, Lot;
```

Comment: Thank you!  This does exactly what I want, even more! (Though I think I'll incorporate RunningQuantity and RemainingDemand, as they are useful)

Comment: @TimLarson - It looked like a typical warehouse stock picking problem.  I need 13 star-bellied Sneetches.  Grab the first box on the star-bellied Sneetch shelf and see if there are enough.  If so, great.  If not, grab the next box.  When you fall off the end of the shelf you grab your paint and a stencil and start looking for Sneetches without stars upon thar's.

Answer (score 1):

*(based on version 4 of question as my WiFi went down for quite some time)*

```
(SELECT
  Pool,
  SUM(Quantity) as Pool_Quantity
FROM
  Pooled_Lots
GROUP BY
  Pool) as Pool_Quantity_Table
```

Now you have a table with the Pool Quantity rolled up into a single value.

Now the complete query:

```
SELECT
  Pool_Consumption.PoolID as Pool,
  Pool_Quantity_Table.Pool_Quantity as Quantity,
  Pool_Consumption.QuantityConsumed as AmtConsumedFromLot,
  (Pool_Quantity_Table.Pool_Quantity - Pool_Consumption.QuantityConsumed) as SurplusOrDefecit
FROM
  Pool_Consumption
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT
    Pool,
    SUM(Quantity) as Pool_Quantity
  FROM
    Pooled_Lots
  GROUP BY
    Pool) as Pool_Quantity_Table
ON (Pool_Consumption.PoolID = Pool_Quantity_Table.Pool);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this, JohnB.  Though having the results split by lots is a bit more helpful in my current situation, this answer does help me understand the solution to my problem as well.  I apologize for the inaccuracies in my original end result table, I thought I had double checked that and didn't see it until you made the revision.

Comment: You are very welcome. I glad that you got a solution to your problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

Habo's answer looks like it works well, but wanted to provide a variation that doesn't require recursion but is still set-based. Without recursion, the solution is simpler and will probably perform better (with the right indexing strategy)

```
/*Raw data setup*/
CREATE TABLE #Pool_Consumption (Id int, [Pool] int, QuantityConsumed int );
CREATE TABLE #Pooled_Lots( Id int, [Pool] int, Lot int, Quantity int );

INSERT INTO #Pool_Consumption ( Id, [Pool], QuantityConsumed )
VALUES (1,1,17),(2,2,8),(3,3,10);

INSERT INTO #Pooled_Lots
VALUES (1,1,1,5),(2,1,2,10),(3,1,3,4),
(4,2,1,7),
(5,3,1,1),(6,3,2,5);


/*Setup work tables
Essentially ranges number each consumption and reserves a range of ID's for each lot*/
SELECT *
    ,LowerRange = 1
    ,UpperRange = QuantityConsumed
INTO #Pool_Consumption_Range
FROM #Pool_Consumption

SELECT *
    ,LowerRange = SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY [Pool] ORDER BY Lot) - Quantity + 1
    ,UpperRange = SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY [Pool] ORDER BY Lot) 
INTO #Pooled_Lots_Range
FROM #Pooled_Lots

SELECT 
     C.[Pool]
    ,L.Lot
    ,L.Quantity
    ,C.QuantityConsumed
    ,QtyFulfilled = SUM(CA.ReservedQty) OVER (PARTITION BY C.[Pool] ORDER BY L.ID)
    ,RemainderInLot = L.Quantity - CA.ReservedQty
    ,RemainingDemand = QuantityConsumed - SUM(CA.ReservedQty) OVER (PARTITION BY C.[Pool] ORDER BY L.ID) 
    ,SurplusOrDefecit = CASE WHEN L.ID = MAX(L.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY C.[Pool]) THEN SUM(L.Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY C.[Pool] ORDER BY L.ID)  - C.QuantityConsumed END
FROM #Pool_Consumption_Range AS C
LEFT JOIN #Pooled_Lots_Range AS L
    ON C.[Pool] = L.[Pool]
    AND (
        /*Overlap between consumption range and lots ranges*/
        C.LowerRange BETWEEN L.LowerRange and L.UpperRange
        OR C.UpperRange BETWEEN L.LowerRange and L.UpperRange
        /*For when entire lots range between consumption range*/
        OR L.UpperRange BETWEEN C.LowerRange AND C.UpperRange
        )
CROSS APPLY (
    /*Finds the count of overlap between order range and inventory range
    Essentially orders all range values and finds the two middle numbers, then calculates the delta of them
    Ex. If you have a range of 2 to 5 and 3 to 6
        It sorts the numbers as 2,3,5,6
        It grabs the second value 3 (OFFSET 1 FETCH 1), then because LEAD runs before OFFSET it grabs the next row so 5
        The delta of 3 and 5 = 2 so there's a 2 number overlap between the two ranges
    */
    SELECT ReservedQty = LEAD(DTA.Points,1) OVER (ORDER BY DTA.Points) - DTA.Points + 1
    FROM (VALUES(C.LowerRange),(C.UpperRange),(L.LowerRange),(L.UpperRange)) AS DTA(Points)
    ORDER BY Points
    OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
            ) AS CA
ORDER BY C.[Pool],L.Lot
```