# Distributing Values SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find a more efficient way of doing this, as I have gone the cursor route and hate the performance hit I get with using cursors in SQL.  I'm trying to distribute payments across items with value and keep track of any remaining amounts.  For instance...

```
Payments             
--------
10,
20

Items
------
5,
5,
10
```

In essence would return that the first payment (10) applied to the first two items and was exhausted.  The second payment (20) applied to the third item and there was 10 left over.  I'm able to accomplish this fine using cursors.  Just curious if anyone had some thoughts on how to do this more efficiently.

Cheers!

Comment: Show us what it looks like with your cursor, and we'll be able to see if something may work better ...

Comment: could you please specify your problem. also it would be useful to see the code of your cursor to explain your question.

Comment: When is a payment "exhausted"? Packing problems are usually non-trivial - and this has nothing to do with using cursors or not.

Comment: From this description comparing the two SUM should be enought to see what left on which side.

Comment: Ah sorry... What I meant by exhausted is when the full amount has been applied to the items.  My cursor currently goes through each payment and inserts into a table variable the items it allocates to.  The items are flagged as fully paid and the next payment (and ID) gets put into the cursor.  If the payment goes over what it can actually pay for.. The rest goes into a separate bucket.  Id like to keep track of which payment(s) actually went over.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: use temporary tables. They are lightning fast compared to cursor.

Comment: You might find something of interest using CTEs [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850368/fifo-first-in-first-out-in-sql-server-2008/10855154#10855154).  Or, better yet, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420173/sql-subtracting-a-depleting-value-from-rows/9421009#9421009).

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: you have date fields you use to sequence the payments and items (which payments are used first/which items are paid first)?

Comment: Yeah... I'm starting from the earliest payment.  All these are stored in their respective tables.  I have dates for both the payments and the items.  I'm using 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an ordered set of IDs for the payments and items you could create a mapping table for items to payments and then do something like this (see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b6f8/4):

```
-- Populate mapping table
INSERT INTO PaymentsForItems (ItemID, PaymentID)
SELECT ItemID,
       (SELECT MIN(PaymentID)
        FROM Payments p1
        WHERE (SELECT SUM(ItemValue)
               FROM Items i2
               WHERE i2.ItemID <= i1.ItemID) <=
              (SELECT SUM(PaymentValue)
               FROM Payments p2
               WHERE p2.PaymentID <= p1.PaymentID))
FROM Items i1;
```

This doesn't show the remainder - not sure how you'd like to represent this but could easily insert a row separately (e.g. with NULLs as the IDs).

Comment: To increase performance further you could also consider including a "cumulative total" column in both tables but this would need to be updated (perhaps by triggers?) whenever the data changes.

Comment: This approach is more on the lines of what I'm looking for (I'd upvote you if I could)... I have all of the payment and item information already in tables currently.  Restructuring the tables/adding triggers aren't really an option for me.  I'd like to just wrap up the whole thing in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cursor, why don't you get all your Items and Payments, and work on them in your code?

It may be quicker, you'll have to bench the 2 ways of doing this.

In Java:

```
PreparedStatement psItems = con.prepareStatement("SELECT itemId,item FROM items");
PreparedStatement psPayments = con.prepareStatement("SELECT payId,payment FROM payments");
ResultSet rsItems = psItems.executeQuery();
ResultSet rsPayments = psPayments.executeQuery();

int currPaymentLeft = 0;
int currentPayId = 0;
int currentItemId = 0;

while(rsItems.next()) {
    int priceItem = rsItems.getInt("item");
    currentItemId = rsItems.getInt("itemId");
    if (currPayment < priceItem) {
        // Here we are in the case where the last payment was over the items it bought.
        // Except if currPayment is 0. In this case, there is no rest.
        if (currPayment > 0) {
            // This is the rest case
            // In currentPayId, we have the Id of a Payment 
            // where there is currPayment left which will be unused.
            // Do whatever you want with this Id and amount.
        }

        currPayment = 0;
        while(rsPayments.next()) {
            currPaymentLeft = rsItems.getInt("payment");
            int payId = rsItems.getInt("payId");
            if(payment >= priceItem) {
                currPaymentLeft -= priceItem;
                // Link currentPayId with currentItemId
                // Create a query, store it in a collection, wo what you want.

                // Get out of this while loop
                break;
            }
            // else, the payment is less than the priceItem
            // so this payment won't be of any use.
            // This is a total rest case
            // In currentPayId, we have the Id of a Payment 
            // where there is currPayment left which will be unused.
            // Do whatever you want with this Id and amount.
        }
    }
    else {
        currPaymentLeft -= priceItem;
        // Link currentPayId with currentItemId because itemId was paid with currentPayId
    }
}
```

Comment: That's sort of what I'm struggling with I suppose?  I'm thinking more on the lines of how I would attack this in Java or VB, and I need a more SQL optimized route.

Comment: @CaptainHammer : updated my post with a double while loop in Java, and in comments all different cases where you store which payment paid which item, and the case where there is some rest, which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you have two distinct, but similar events - a new payment is received, and a new cost item is created.  At each juncture, you need to update the other table, so it seems that either a Stored Procedure or a trigger is required, depending on your insert mechanism.

When a new item is created, you find the earliest payment with money outstanding, and decrease it by the cost of the item.

Similarly, when a new payment is created, you distribute the amount ( `@amount` ) in order.

```
update items
set 
    paid = 
         case when @amount>=runningTotal then items.amount 
         else 
            case when @amount - (runningTotal - (amount-paid))>0 
                then @amount - (runningTotal - (amount-paid)) 
                else 0 
            end
         end        
from 
    items 
cross apply 
    (
        select sum(amount-paid) as runningTotal 
        from items
        where id <= items.id
    ) as rt
```

(Using atomic transactions, of course)

Answer (score 0):

I tested this piece of code with SQL server 2005, and it seemed OK.
Hope it can help some.

```
WITH tItems
AS
(
SELECT A.ItemId, A.ItemValue, (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(B.ItemValue), 0)
                               FROM Items B
                               WHERE B.ItemId < A.ItemId) AS PrevItemTotal,

                               (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(C.ItemValue), 0)
                                FROM Items C
                                WHERE C.ItemId <= A.ItemId) AS CurrItemTotal
FROM Items A
),
tPayments
AS
(
SELECT A.PaymentId, A.PaymentValue, (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(B.PaymentValue), 0)
                                     FROM Payments B
                                     WHERE B.PaymentId < A.PaymentId) AS PrevPaymentTotal,

                                    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(C.PaymentValue), 0)
                                     FROM Payments C
                                     WHERE C.PaymentId <= A.PaymentId) AS CurrPaymentTotal
FROM Payments A
),
tDistribution
AS
(
SELECT *,
CASE
    WHEN PrevPaymentTotal - PrevItemTotal <= 0 THEN
        CASE
            WHEN PaymentValue - (PrevItemTotal-PrevPaymentTotal) <= ItemValue THEN PaymentValue - (PrevItemTotal-PrevPaymentTotal)
            ELSE ItemValue
        END
    ELSE -- PrevPaymentTotal - PrevItemTotal > 0
        CASE
            WHEN ItemValue - (PrevPaymentTotal - PrevItemTotal) < PaymentValue THEN ItemValue - (PrevPaymentTotal - PrevItemTotal)
            ELSE PaymentValue
        END
END AS Distribution
FROM tItems X, tPayments Y
WHERE Y.CurrPaymentTotal > X.PrevItemTotal AND Y.PrevPaymentTotal < X.CurrItemTotal
)

SELECT ItemId, ItemValue, PaymentId, PaymentValue, Distribution,
ItemValue - SUM (Distribution) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId) AS Remaining
FROM tDistribution
```

Comment: Thanks for editing the code to make it look much better, Bummi. I am new to the forum, and just wanna post a solution quickly to help someone in need, sorry for the mess.