# Best Way to Sequentially Parse Through a Table in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm writing a stored procedure in SQL Server and hoping someone can suggest a more computationally efficient way to handle this problem:

I have a table of **Customer Orders** (i.e., "product demand") data that contains 3000 line items.  Each record expresses the Order Qty for a specific product.

I also have another table of **Production Orders** (i.e., "product supply") data that contains about 200 line items.  Each record expresses the Qty Available for each specific product.

The problem is that there is typically less supply than demand and, therefore, the Custom Order table contains an Allocation Priority value that shows each Customer Order's position in line to receive product.

What's the best way to allocate Qty Available in Production Orders to the Order Qty in Customer Orders?  Note that you can't allocate more to each Customer Order than has been ordered.

I can do this by creating a WHILE loop and doing the allocation product-by-product, line-by-line but it is very slow.

Is there a faster set-based way to approach this problem?

Comment: what does your current line-by-line logic look like?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420173/sql-subtracting-a-depleting-value-from-rows) may help.

Comment: HABO, I think you set me off in the right direction!  I was not aware of Common Table Expressions (CTEs) as a set-based way of recursively processing records, but I think this is what I need here.  I have tried with no success to implement a CTE, but I will keep working on it.  Thank you!!

Comment: To answer the previous questions, we're running SQL Server 2008 r2.  I have since dumped my code but suffice it to say that I took a procedural approach using temporary tables and WHILE loops to step through each row recursively.  As I said below, I think Common Table Expressions (CTE) will probably perform better here just based on what little I've learned about them so far.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have data to test against.  This would not try and fill partial qty.

```
 select orders.custID, orders.priority, orders.prodID, orders.qty, SUM(cumu.qty) as 'cumu'
 from orders 
 join orders as cumu 
 on cumu.prodID = orders.prodID 
    and cumu.priority <= orders.priority
 join available 
 on availble.prodID = orders.prodID  
 group by orders.custID, orders.priority, orders.prodID, orders.qty 
 having SUM(cumu.qty) < availble.qty
 order by orders.custID, orders.priority, orders.prodID
```

Comment: That's great!  I haven't tested it yet but I agree that your approach only addresses full allocations, but that will cover >90% of the orders I can follow afterwards and clean it up by doing the remaining partial allocations.afterwards.

Comment: If you change it to cumu.priority < orders.priority it should even display the last order that possibly cannot be filled.   If this answered question then please check it as an answer.