# Iterative CTE to solve

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

I've been working on a CTE that will effectively create invoice lines based on some job items. Given:

```
Create table JobLines (line int, code varchar(10), qty decimal(9,2))  
go

insert into JobLines values (1, '2222A', 1)  
insert into JobLines values (2, '2222B', 3)  
insert into JobLines values (3, '2222A', -1)  
insert into JobLines values (4, '2222C', 2)  
insert into JobLines values (5, '2222D', 1)  
insert into JobLines values (6, '2222B', -1)  
insert into JobLines values (7, '2222A', 2)  
insert into JobLines values (8, '2222B', -1)  
insert into JobLines values (9,'2222A', -1)  
go
```

### I would like a CTE that can:

Subtract every negative line from the positive line before it matching on code.

### The result should be:

```
Line Code    Quantity 
1    222A    0          
2    222B    1          
4    222C    2          
5    222D    1          
7    222A    1
```

Line 1 - 0 (minus from line 3).
Line 2 - 1 (minus from lines 6 and 8).
Line 4 - no change.
Line 5 - no change.
Line 7 - 1 (minus from line 9).

I came pretty close a few times. The main problem is that I can't get the desired result for Lines 2 or 7, because I can't group together effectively the 2 lines I need to subtract.

My approach was to try and iterate over the positive lines, fetching the negative rows for each.

Sample code I am working on:

```
;with cte_positive_rows as (select line, code, qty
    ,row_number() over (partition by code order by line) code_instance
    ,row_number() over (order by line) row_sequence
from jobLines
where qty > 0
)
,cte_negative_rows as (
    select line, code, qty
    ,row_number() over (partition by code order by line) code_instance
    ,row_number() over (order by line) row_sequence
from jobLines
where qty < 0
)
,cte_iterator as(
--base case - start with line 1 from cte_postive_rows...

select min(base.line) line, base.code
    ,cast(sum(base.qty + neg.qty) as     decimal(9,2)) total_qty
    ,base.code_instance
    ,base.row_sequence, base.row_sequence + 1 as next_row
    from cte_positive_rows base
    inner join cte_negative_rows neg
    on
    neg.row_sequence = base.row_sequence
    and neg.code_instance = base.code_instance
    where base.row_sequence = 1
    group by base.code, base.code_instance, base.row_sequence

    union all

    --iterative case - each line..
    -- the iterative case should returns all the rows that needed modifying

    select row.line, row.code
    ,cast(row.qty + neg.qty as decimal(9,2)) qty, row.code_instance
    ,row.row_sequence
    ,row.row_sequence + 1 as next_row
    from cte_positive_rows row 
    inner join cte_negative_rows neg
    on
    neg.row_sequence = row.row_sequence
    and neg.code_instance = row.code_instance
    inner join cte_iterator cte
    on row.row_sequence = cte.next_row
)

-- get all the modified and non-modifed rows with joins

select pos.line, pos.code, pos.qty, pos.code_instance, pos.row_sequence
from cte_positive_rows pos
left outer join cte_iterator i
on pos.row_sequence = i.row_sequence
where i.row_sequence IS NULL
union all 
select line, code, total_qty, code_instance, row_sequence from cte_iterator
order by row_sequence
```

Not quite there, the results of the above:

```
1   2222A   0.00    1   1
2   2222B   2.00    1   2
4   2222C   2.00    1   3
5   2222D   1.00    1   4
7   2222A   2.00    2   5
```

Is my dream possible?!

Comment: Maybe I need to use cross apply in some way to key the negative rows properly

Comment: Something horrifically more complicated is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420173/sql-subtracting-a-depleting-value-from-rows).  Might be educational.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a look. Can you see a way to make the code_instance perform as a better key on the negative rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your requirements completely, but this appears to do what you need:

```
select line, code, qty + isnull((
    -- get the sum of all negative values...
    select sum(j1.qty)
    from JobLines j1
    where 
        -- ...for the same code, but with a higher line number...
        j1.code = PositiveLines.code and 
        j1.line > PositiveLines.line and 
        j1.qty < 0 and
        -- ...where there is no positive value on a previous line
        not exists (
            select * 
            from JobLines
            where 
                code = j1.code and 
                qty > 0 and 
                line > j1.line)
    ),0)
from
(   
select
    line, code, qty
from
    JobLines
where
    qty > 0
) PositiveLines
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I got caught up with CTEs too much.. wrong tool for the job in this case it seems. Would still be nice to see it achieved in that way for the learning but this works great - can't argue with the results! Much simpler than the road I was determined to take :)

Comment: Damn - after coming back to this, it only works for the problem data. If you introduce a line 10, or delete line 9, it does not work