# SQL DIfference of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables - Cheque and Policy. Below is the structure. For clarity this is the bare minimum structure

Table Name: Cheque

> **Columns:**
>   ChequeId.
>   ChequeNumber,
>   Amount,
>   LastUpdated

Table Name: Policy

> **Columns**    PolicyId,
>       PolicyNumber,
>       ChequeId,
>       Amount,
>       LastUpdated

I want to have a query which returns me following

```
ChequeNumber,PolicyId,ChequeAmount,PolicyAmount,Difference
```

One cheque can be mapped to multiple policies (one to many relationship)
Now if a cheque is matched to say 2 policies and the sum of the amount of those two policies is greater than the cheque amount, I should see the difference, but only for the second policy.It's assumed that the first policy got fully matched.(perhaps use last updated column??) So the output would be

```
ChequeNumber  PolicyNumber  ChequeAmount   PolicyAmount    Difference    
   1               1             200          100           0 
   1               2             200          200           100
```

Below is what I have written

```
SELECT chequeNumber AS chequeNumber
      ,COALESCE(p.policyNumber, '') AS PolicyNumber
      ,c.amount AS chequeamount
      ,p.Amount As PolicyAmount
      ,(c.Amount) - SUM(p.Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY c.ChequeID) AS Difference
FROM Cheque c 
LEFT JOIN Policy AS p 
    ON p.ChequeId=c.ChequeId 
GROUP BY chequeNumber, policyNumber,c.amount,p.Amount,c.ChequeID
```

This gives me the difference in both the rows (below table) and not just the last policy which was mapped.

```
ChequeNumber  PolicyNumber  ChequeAmount   PolicyAmount    Difference    
   1               1             200          100           -100 
   1               2             200          200           -100
```

I'm using SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420173/sql-subtracting-a-depleting-value-from-rows) SO question deals with consuming inventory from multiple lots in inventory. Sounds like a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008 you have limited support to WINDOW Functions, so you need a self join:

```
WITH DATA AS
(
    SELECT chequeNumber AS chequeNumber
          ,COALESCE(p.policyNumber, '') AS PolicyNumber
          ,c.amount AS chequeamount
          ,p.Amount As PolicyAmount
          ,P.MovingSum
    FROM Cheque c 
    LEFT JOIN  (SELECT P1.PolicyId
                      ,P1.PolicyNumber
                      ,P1.ChequeId
                      ,P1.Amount
                      ,P1.Amount + COALESCE(P2.Amount, 0) AS MovingSum
                FROM Policy AS P1
                LEFT JOIN Policy AS P2
                    ON P1.ChequeId = P2.ChequeId
                    AND P1.PolicyId > P2.PolicyId
                    AND P1.PolicyNumber > P2.PolicyNumber) AS p 
        ON p.ChequeId = c.ChequeId
    GROUP BY chequeNumber, policyNumber, c.amount, p.Amount, c.ChequeID, p.MovingSum
)
SELECT chequeNumber
      ,PolicyNumber
      ,chequeamount
      ,PolicyAmount
      ,CASE WHEN MovingSum > PolicyAmount THEN MovingSum - chequeamount ELSE 0 END AS Difference
FROM DATA;
```

Comment: Thanks but it still gives me the same output, although now the difference is coming as positive

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly you need to calculate the difference between
policy amount - (cheque amount - amount already allocated to previous policies)
considering the allocation is in policynumber order this should work:

```
SELECT chequeNumber AS chequeNumber
      ,COALESCE(p.policyNumber, '') AS PolicyNumber
      ,c.amount AS chequeamount
      ,p.Amount As PolicyAmount
      ,p.amount - 
      CASE WHEN
      (c.Amount - (SELECT SUM(p1.amount) FROM cheque c1 LEFT JOIN policy p1 ON p1.chequeid=c1.chequeid AND p1.policynumber < p.policynumber)) < 0   THEN 0
      ELSE  (c.Amount - (SELECT SUM(p1.amount) FROM cheque c1 LEFT JOIN policy p1 ON p1.chequeid=c1.chequeid AND p1.policynumber < p.policynumber)) END Difference
FROM Cheque c 
LEFT JOIN Policy AS p 
    ON p.ChequeId=c.ChequeId 
GROUP BY chequeNumber, policyNumber,c.amount,p.Amount,c.ChequeID
```