# Subtract variable from column while variable has remaining value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a column with different numerical values. And I have a numeric variable called `X` with a value of 50000.

```
  rownumber           col1 
 --------------------------
     1                5000
     2                1000
     3               10000
     4               12000
     5                 300
     6               35000

 DECLARE @X AS decimal(18,2) = 50000
```

I need somehow cover the value from col1 to zero while the variable x have value. How to get the following result?

```
  rownumber            col1      col2         

     1                 5000       0     
     2                 1000       0      
     3                10000       0      
     5                  300       0      
     6                35000     13300
```

if @X = 1000 then result should be:

```
 rownumber            col1        col2         

     1                 5000       4000        
     2                 1000       1000       
     3                10000      10000     
     4                12000      12000     
     5                  300        300      
     6                35000      35000
```

Comment: What EXACTLY do you want the output to be? (And where is `col2` coming from?)

Comment: i need somehow cover the value from col1 to zero while the variable x is has value..

Comment: Looks like a variation on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420173/sql-subtracting-a-depleting-value-from-rows) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with running sums:

```
with cte as(select *, sum(col1) over(order by rn) as s from t)
select rn, col1, 0 as col2 from cte where s <= 1000 
union all
select * from (select top 1 rn, col1, s - 1000 as col2 from cte where s > 1000 order by rn)t
union all
select * from (select rn, col1, col1 as col2 from cte where s > 1000 order by rn offset 1 row)t
```

This is the version that is born in my head without checking. I can not check right now, but I think it should work and it is setbased.

The idea is to make a running sum:

```
rownumber  col1   s        
1          5000   5000    
2          1000   6000   
3          10000  16000    
4          12000  28000
5          300    28300      
6          35000  63300
```

Now you are selecting all rows where `s <= 50000`. This will give you `rn{1,2,3,4,5}`. Note you make `col2` all zeros. In second union you are selecting first row where `s > 50000`. This will give you `rn{6}`. Note `col2 is 63300 - 50000 = 13300`. Now if you have additional rows then you are selecting those in third union except of first row which we already selected in second union.

Comment: what if @X have value 1000 then first row in col2 need to be 4000, and second 1000, third 10000, four 12000, five 300 and six 35000

Comment: then again what if @X is 7000 then first row will be 0, second 0, third 8000 and four 12000, five 300, six 35000. I need to cover all cases.