# FIFO Inventory Aging

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, fifo

Apologies in advance for the explanation. Any help would be appreciated.

We have the following table:

[image]

This table contains 6 buckets:

- 360 : assets or liabilities held for 360 days or more
- 181 - 360 : assets or liabilities held between 181 - 360 days
- 91 - 180 : assets or liabilities held between 91 - 180 days
- 61 - 90 : assets or liabilities held between 61 - 90 days
- 31 - 60 : assets or liabilities held between 31 - 60 days
- =<30 : assets or liabilities held for 30 days or less

We want to apply the following logic to get the results shown below:

[image]

The logic is as follows:

- Start at the column 360 and subtract the liabilities from the assets.
- If the result is a liability and we have assets remaining in the lower buckets  then subtract the asset from the next column from it and so on until we either go through all the asset buckets or we have 0 assets and liabilities for that bucket.
- If the result is an asset and we have liabilities remaining in the lower buckets then subtract the liabilities from the next column from it and so on until we either go through all the asset buckets or we have 0 assets and liabilities for that bucket.
- When we subtract a lower bucket (31-60) from a higher bucket (91-180) if we manage to completely clear the remaining asset or liability and still have some asset or liability remaining from the lower bucket then the value within the lower bucket then becomes the remainder and it will be used in the evaluation of the next bucket. ( see below example for this scenario)

so the set:

[image]

will become:

[image]

I am trying to avoid using loops and would like to achieve this using sets rather than cursors. I had a few goes at it myself but can't quite get the results I need. [This article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/set-based-speed-phreakery-the-fifo-stock-inventory-sql-problem/) helped but not quite what I need.

Script to generate test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #LINE ([Cusip] VARCHAR(32),
                    [TradingActivity] VARCHAR(10),
                    [NotionalAmount] DECIMAL (20,2),
                    [TradeDate]  DATE,
                    [ValDate] DATE)

INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-01-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-01-12','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-07-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-07-10','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-10-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-10-08','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-11-06','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-11-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-12-06','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-12-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-01-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-01-12','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-07-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-07-10','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-10-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-10-08','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-11-06','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-11-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-12-06','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-12-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0002','BUY','2000000.00','2015-01-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0002','SELL','1000000.00','2015-01-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0003','SELL','2000000.00','2015-07-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0003','BUY','1000000.00','2015-07-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0004','BUY','1000000.00','2015-10-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0004','SELL','2000000.00','2015-10-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0005','SELL','1000000.00','2015-11-06','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0005','BUY','2000000.00','2015-11-06','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0006','BUY','1000000.00','2015-11-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0006','SELL','1000000.00','2015-11-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0007','SELL','2000000.00','2015-12-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0007','BUY','2000000.00','2015-12-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0008','SELL','1000000.00','2016-01-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0008','BUY','2000000.00','2015-01-08','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0009','BUY','1000000.00','2016-01-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0009','SELL','2000000.00','2015-07-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0010','SELL','2000000.00','2016-01-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0010','BUY','1000000.00','2015-10-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0011','BUY','2000000.00','2016-01-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0011','SELL','1000000.00','2015-11-06','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0012','SELL','1000000.00','2016-01-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0012','BUY','1000000.00','2015-11-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0013','SELL','2000000.00','2015-12-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0013','BUY','2000000.00','2016-01-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0014','SELL','2000000.00','2015-12-03','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0014','BUY','1000000.00','2015-01-01','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0014','SELL','2000000.00','2015-07-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0014','BUY','2000000.00','2015-10-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0015B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-12-03','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0015A','BUY','4000000.00','2015-04-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0015A','SELL','3000000.00','2015-07-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0015B','BUY','2000000.00','2015-10-01','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0016B','SELL','2000000.00','2015-12-01','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0016A','BUY','3000000.00','2015-04-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0016A','SELL','4000000.00','2015-07-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0016B','BUY','1000000.00','2015-10-01','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0017A','SELL','3000000.00','2015-12-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0017B','SELL','2000000.00','2015-12-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0017A','BUY','4000000.00','2015-10-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0017B','BUY','1000000.00','2015-10-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0018B','SELL','2000000.00','2015-12-01','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0018A','BUY','4000000.00','2015-04-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0018B','BUY','1000000.00','2015-07-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0018A','SELL','3000000.00','2015-10-01','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0019B','BUY','8000000.00','2015-12-03','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0019A','SELL','1000000.00','2015-01-01','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0019B','BUY','5000000.00','2015-07-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0019A','SELL','7000000.00','2015-09-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0020B','SELL','8000000.00','2015-12-03','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0020A','SELL','1000000.00','2015-01-01','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0020B','BUY','5000000.00','2015-07-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0020A','BUY','7000000.00','2015-09-02','2016-01-07')
```

Comment: I think you need to do some leg work, not define your business logic here...

Comment: You explanation is litle great but litle confusing, Can you reproduce those step with the sample data so we understand it better?

Comment: This sounds like a variation on consuming inventory on a FIFO basis. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420173/sql-subtracting-a-depleting-value-from-rows/9421009#9421009) answer may provide some hints.

Comment: wow how lucky @HABO still here to bring you one answer from 2012, I cant find my own answers from one month ago :(

Comment: @HABO I'm going to give this a go based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420173/sql-subtracting-a-depleting-value-from-rows/9421009#9421009

Comment: I will let you all know if it worked or not

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I searched for `user:me is:answer depleting`, otherwise I'd never find it. [Search help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Comment: @HABO Wow nice feature. Thanks.

Comment: @KamranFarzami add a script with schema and data sample for us to use. Also, what have you done so far? Can you reproduce those step with the sample data so we understand it better?

Comment: @Horaciux I have a solution but it has a bug in it which I'm trying to resolve. I will shortly add a script for the sample data.

Comment: The numbers in your given example don't seem to add up according to your own rules.

Comment: @TomH you are absolutely right there I will edit my question and answer because I have it working and it has been tested now.

Comment: @TomH I have now updated the answer and the test data set in the question hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error this implementation is giving me the desired results:

```
CREATE TABLE #LINE ([Cusip] VARCHAR(32),
                    [TradingActivity] VARCHAR(10),
                    [NotionalAmount] DECIMAL (20,2),
                    [TradeDate]  DATE,
                    [ValDate] DATE)

INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-01-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-01-12','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-07-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-07-10','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-10-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-10-08','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-11-06','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-11-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-12-06','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_A','BUY','1000000.00','2015-12-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-01-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-01-12','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-07-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-07-10','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-10-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-10-08','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-11-06','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-11-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-12-06','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0001_B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-12-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0002','BUY','2000000.00','2015-01-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0002','SELL','1000000.00','2015-01-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0003','SELL','2000000.00','2015-07-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0003','BUY','1000000.00','2015-07-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0004','BUY','1000000.00','2015-10-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0004','SELL','2000000.00','2015-10-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0005','SELL','1000000.00','2015-11-06','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0005','BUY','2000000.00','2015-11-06','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0006','BUY','1000000.00','2015-11-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0006','SELL','1000000.00','2015-11-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0007','SELL','2000000.00','2015-12-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0007','BUY','2000000.00','2015-12-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0008','SELL','1000000.00','2016-01-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0008','BUY','2000000.00','2015-01-08','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0009','BUY','1000000.00','2016-01-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0009','SELL','2000000.00','2015-07-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0010','SELL','2000000.00','2016-01-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0010','BUY','1000000.00','2015-10-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0011','BUY','2000000.00','2016-01-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0011','SELL','1000000.00','2015-11-06','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0012','SELL','1000000.00','2016-01-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0012','BUY','1000000.00','2015-11-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0013','SELL','2000000.00','2015-12-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0013','BUY','2000000.00','2016-01-07','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0014','SELL','2000000.00','2015-12-03','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0014','BUY','1000000.00','2015-01-01','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0014','SELL','2000000.00','2015-07-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0014','BUY','2000000.00','2015-10-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0015B','SELL','1000000.00','2015-12-03','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0015A','BUY','4000000.00','2015-04-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0015A','SELL','3000000.00','2015-07-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0015B','BUY','2000000.00','2015-10-01','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0016B','SELL','2000000.00','2015-12-01','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0016A','BUY','3000000.00','2015-04-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0016A','SELL','4000000.00','2015-07-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0016B','BUY','1000000.00','2015-10-01','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0017A','SELL','3000000.00','2015-12-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0017B','SELL','2000000.00','2015-12-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0017A','BUY','4000000.00','2015-10-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0017B','BUY','1000000.00','2015-10-09','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0018B','SELL','2000000.00','2015-12-01','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0018A','BUY','4000000.00','2015-04-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0018B','BUY','1000000.00','2015-07-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0018A','SELL','3000000.00','2015-10-01','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0019B','BUY','8000000.00','2015-12-03','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0019A','SELL','1000000.00','2015-01-01','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0019B','BUY','5000000.00','2015-07-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0019A','SELL','7000000.00','2015-09-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0020B','SELL','8000000.00','2015-12-03','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0020A','SELL','1000000.00','2015-01-01','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0020B','BUY','5000000.00','2015-07-02','2016-01-07')
INSERT INTO #LINE VALUES('T0020A','BUY','7000000.00','2015-09-02','2016-01-07')

-- Assign LOT numbers to each record based on CUSIP, TradingActivity, and Bucket. And assign rankings to the buckets used for ordering later on.
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RollUp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #RollUp;

       SELECT  A.[Cusip], 
             A.[TradingActivity], 
             A.[NotionalAmount],
             [LOT] =ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.[Cusip],A.[TradingActivity],CASE  WHEN DATEDIFF(day,A.[TradeDate],A.[ValDate]) BETWEEN 0 AND 30 THEN '0'  --'[=<30]' 
               WHEN DATEDIFF(day,A.[TradeDate],A.[ValDate]) BETWEEN 31 AND 60 THEN '1'  --'[31-60]' 
               WHEN DATEDIFF(day,A.[TradeDate],A.[ValDate]) BETWEEN 61 AND 90 THEN '2'  --'[61-90]' 
               WHEN DATEDIFF(day,A.[TradeDate],A.[ValDate]) BETWEEN 91 AND 180 THEN '3'  --'[91-180]' 
               WHEN DATEDIFF(day,A.[TradeDate],A.[ValDate]) BETWEEN 181 AND 360 THEN '4'  --'[181-360]'  
               WHEN DATEDIFF(day,A.[TradeDate],A.[ValDate]) > 360 THEN '5'  --'[+360]' 
               END ORDER BY A.[TradeDate] ) 
             ,
             [Bucket]= CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,[TradeDate],[ValDate]) BETWEEN 0 AND 30 THEN '0'  --'[=<30]' 
               WHEN DATEDIFF(day,[TradeDate],[ValDate]) BETWEEN 31 AND 60 THEN '1'  --'[31-60]' 
               WHEN DATEDIFF(day,[TradeDate],[ValDate]) BETWEEN 61 AND 90 THEN '2'  --'[61-90]' 
               WHEN DATEDIFF(day,[TradeDate],[ValDate]) BETWEEN 91 AND 180 THEN '3'  --'[91-180]' 
               WHEN DATEDIFF(day,[TradeDate],[ValDate]) BETWEEN 181 AND 360 THEN '4'  --'[181-360]'  
               WHEN DATEDIFF(day,[TradeDate],[ValDate]) > 360 THEN '5'  --'[+360]' 
               END INTO #RollUp
       FROM #Line AS A 
       ORDER BY [Cusip],[TradeDate]  

-- Apply (+/-) sign to NotionalAmount and derive the SUM of NotionalAmount based on  CUSIP, TradingActivity, and Bucket
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP;

       SELECT  A.[Cusip], 
             A.[Bucket],
             A.[LOT],  
             A.[NotionalAmount],
             [SignedNotionalAmount] = CASE WHEN A.[TradingActivity] = 'BUY' THEN  A.[NotionalAmount] ELSE 0-A.[NotionalAmount] END,
             A.[TradingActivity],  
             [SumNotionalAmount] = SUM(A.[NotionalAmount])OVER(PARTITION BY A.[Cusip],A.[TradingActivity], A.[Bucket] ) INTO #TEMP      
       FROM #RollUp AS A     
       ORDER BY    A.[Bucket] DESC,
                A.[LOT] ASC 

-- Rank the notional ammounts for each CUSIP based on TradeActivity
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP2; 

       SELECT  A.[Cusip], 
             A.[Bucket], 
             [SumNotionalAmount] = SUM(A.[SignedNotionalAmount]),
             [SignedNotionalAmountRanked] = RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY A.[Cusip],CASE   WHEN SUM(A.[SignedNotionalAmount]) > 0 THEN 'BUY' 
                                                                ELSE 'SELL' END  
                                                ORDER BY A.Bucket DESC)  INTO #TEMP2
       FROM #TEMP AS A
       GROUP BY    A.[Cusip],  
                A.[Bucket] 


-- Calculate Sum of the Notional amount based on FIFO algorithm at CUSIP level and place in correct bucket(s)
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP3') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP3; 

       SELECT  A.[Cusip],  A.[Bucket] AS ABucket,B.[Bucket] AS BBucket, A.[SumNotionalAmount] AS ASumNotionalAmount ,  B.[SumNotionalAmount]  AS BSumNotionalAmount, 
             [Bucket] = CASE WHEN ABS(A.[SumNotionalAmount])>ABS(B.[SumNotionalAmount])  THEN CASE A.[Bucket]  WHEN 0 THEN '=<30' 
                                    WHEN 1 THEN '31-60' 
                                    WHEN 2 THEN '61-90' 
                                    WHEN 3 THEN '91-180' 
                                    WHEN 4 THEN '181-360'  
                                    WHEN 5 THEN '+360' 
                                    END
                          WHEN ABS(A.[SumNotionalAmount])<ABS(B.[SumNotionalAmount])  THEN CASE B.[Bucket]  WHEN 0 THEN '=<30' 
                                    WHEN 1 THEN '31-60' 
                                    WHEN 2 THEN '61-90' 
                                    WHEN 3 THEN '91-180' 
                                    WHEN 4 THEN '181-360'  
                                    WHEN 5 THEN '+360' 
                                    END
                          WHEN (ABS(A.[SumNotionalAmount])=ABS(B.[SumNotionalAmount]) AND A.[SumNotionalAmount]>B.[SumNotionalAmount])  THEN CASE B.[Bucket]  WHEN 0 THEN '=<30' 
                                    WHEN 1 THEN '31-60' 
                                    WHEN 2 THEN '61-90' 
                                    WHEN 3 THEN '91-180' 
                                    WHEN 4 THEN '181-360'  
                                    WHEN 5 THEN '+360' 
                                    END
                          WHEN (ABS(A.[SumNotionalAmount])=ABS(B.[SumNotionalAmount]) AND A.[SumNotionalAmount]<B.[SumNotionalAmount])  THEN CASE A.[Bucket]  WHEN 0 THEN '=<30' 
                                    WHEN 1 THEN '31-60' 
                                    WHEN 2 THEN '61-90' 
                                    WHEN 3 THEN '91-180' 
                                    WHEN 4 THEN '181-360'  
                                    WHEN 5 THEN '+360' 
                                    END
                          ELSE CASE A.[Bucket]  WHEN 0 THEN '=<30' 
                                    WHEN 1 THEN '31-60' 
                                    WHEN 2 THEN '61-90' 
                                    WHEN 3 THEN '91-180' 
                                    WHEN 4 THEN '181-360'  
                                    WHEN 5 THEN '+360' 
                                    END
                      END ,
                       [RunningSumNotionalAmount] = SUM(A.[SumNotionalAmount]+B.[SumNotionalAmount] )OVER(PARTITION BY A.[Cusip] )  
                      ,
             [SumNotionalAmount] = CASE  WHEN B.[Bucket] IS NOT NULL THEN A.[SumNotionalAmount]+B.[SumNotionalAmount] 
                                    ELSE A.SumNotionalAmount 
                                END INTO #TEMP3
       FROM    #TEMP2 AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN 
             #TEMP2 AS B ON  A.[Cusip] = B.[Cusip] AND
                          A.[SignedNotionalAmountRanked] = B.[SignedNotionalAmountRanked] AND
                          A.[Bucket] <>  B.[Bucket]  
       WHERE  (A.Bucket > B.Bucket  OR 
             B.Bucket IS NULL) 
       ORDER BY    A.Cusip,
                A.Bucket

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP4') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP4; 
SELECT *, (SELECT  SUM(i.[SumNotionalAmount])
             FROM    #TEMP3 AS i  
             WHERE   i.[Cusip] = s.[Cusip] AND                    
                    i.[Bucket] < s.[Bucket] 
               ) AS RollingStock , HasRemainder =  ABS([RunningSumNotionalAmount]) + s.[SumNotionalAmount]  INTO #TEMP4
FROM #TEMP3   AS s 



 SELECT [Cusip],
       [=<30],
       [31-60],
       [61-90],
       [91-180],
       [181-360],
       [+360]
FROM 
(   SELECT  [Cusip],
       [Bucket], 
       [SumNotionalAmount] = CASE    WHEN    SUM([RollingStock]+ [HasRemainder] )OVER(PARTITION BY  [Cusip] ) IS NOT NULL AND 
                                    [HasRemainder] IS NOT NULL THEN ISNULL([RollingStock],0) 
                             ELSE [SumNotionalAmount] 
                        END 
    FROM #TEMP4 ) p
PIVOT
(   SUM([SumNotionalAmount] )
    FOR [Bucket] IN (   [=<30],
                    [31-60],
                    [61-90],
                    [91-180],
                    [181-360],
                    [+360]  )
) AS pvt
```

The results:

[image]