# SQL Warehouse Stock Picking Consumption Larger than Quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have pools of stock separated into lots. An order comes in and we fill that order from its designated pool starting with the first lot. Sometimes an order comes in that is larger than all of the lots in a pool, and we need to go to a different pool to acquire the stock.

I found [this very helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420173/sql-subtracting-a-depleting-value-from-rows) that describes almost exactly what I would like, but the answer is one step away from what I need the data to show.

Sample stock pools, lots and quantities:

```
+----+------+-----+----------+
| Id | Pool | Lot | Quantity |
+----+------+-----+----------+
|  1 |    1 |   1 |        5 |
|  2 |    1 |   2 |       10 |
|  3 |    1 |   3 |        4 |
|  4 |    2 |   1 |        7 |
|  5 |    3 |   1 |        1 |
|  6 |    3 |   2 |        5 |
+----+------+-----+----------+
```

Sample Orders:

```
+----+------+------------------+
| Id | Pool | QuantityConsumed |
+----+------+------------------+
|  1 |    1 |               17 |
|  2 |    2 |                8 |
|  3 |    3 |                6 |
+----+------+------------------+
```

Using HABO 's answer from the linked question gets the following result:

```
+------+-----+----------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
| Pool | Lot | Quantity | QuantityConsumed | RunningQuantity | RemainingDemand | SurplusOrDeficit |
+------+-----+----------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
|    1 |   1 |        5 |               17 |               0 |              12 | NULL             |
|    1 |   2 |       10 |               17 |               0 |               2 | NULL             |
|    1 |   3 |        4 |               17 |               2 |               0 | 2                |
|    2 |   1 |        7 |                8 |               0 |               1 | -1               |
|    3 |   1 |        1 |                6 |               0 |               5 | NULL             |
|    3 |   2 |        5 |                6 |               0 |               0 | 0                |
+------+-----+----------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

However, I would like the pool 2 order to then go to the prior pool and take from it if there is a surplus.

Final Wanted Result:

```
+------+-----+----------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
| Pool | Lot | Quantity | QuantityConsumed | RunningQuantity | RemainingDemand | SurplusOrDeficit |
+------+-----+----------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
|    1 |   1 |        5 |               17 |               0 |              12 | NULL             |
|    1 |   2 |       10 |               17 |               0 |               2 | NULL             |
|    1 |   3 |        4 |               17 |               1 |               0 | 1                |
|    2 |   1 |        7 |                8 |               0 |               0 | 0               |
|    3 |   1 |        1 |                6 |               0 |               5 | NULL             |
|    3 |   2 |        5 |                6 |               0 |               0 |  0               |
+------+-----+----------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

I was thinking there couple be a temp table strep prior to the link's solution where the pool order quantity is checked against the pool's quantity available, but then I don't know how to split the order so the additional stock needed is taken from a previous pool.

Thoughts or suggestions would be helpful. I am using SQL Server 2014, but would also like to do this on a recent version of DB2 as we are transitioning systems.

Comment: I am thinking either quantity consumed must be split into different pools being capped at the maximum quantity in the pool or another recursive CTE needs to be done on the result where Running quantity is assigned as quantity and Deficits are assigned as quantity consumed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to work directly with the joined table you provided (call it `wh`), where I added an `id` column for obvious reasons.

[Rextester demo:](http://rextester.com/UOR57880)

```
create table wh (Id int, Pool int, Lot int, Quantity int, QuantityConsumed int, RunningQuantity int, RemainingDemand int, SurplusOrDeficit int);
GO
insert into wh values (1,1,1,5,17,0,12,NULL);
insert into wh values (2,1,2,10,17,0,2,NULL);
insert into wh values (3,1,3,4,17,2,0,2);
insert into wh values (4,2,1,7,8,0,1,-1);
insert into wh values (5,3,1,1,6,0,7,NULL);
insert into wh values (6,3,2,5,6,0,2,0);

declare @continue int, @d_id int, @s_id int, @deficit int, @max_surplus int;
set @continue = 1;
while @continue = 1
begin
    -- Find the first pool with deficit:
    select @d_id = min(id) from wh where SurplusOrDeficit < 0;
    if @d_id is null
    begin
        -- We are done, all demand has been satisfied
        set @continue = 0;
    end
    else 
    begin
        select @deficit = -SurplusOrDeficit from wh where id = @d_id;
        -- Find the first pool (if such exists) to satisfy the remaining demand for id = @d_id:
        select @s_id = min(id) from wh where SurplusOrDeficit >= @deficit;
        if @s_id is null
        begin
            -- Partially satisfy the remaining demand from a pool which has the biggest surplus:
            select @max_surplus = max(SurplusOrDeficit) from wh where SurplusOrDeficit > 0;
            if @max_surplus is not null
            begin
                select @s_id = min(id) from wh where SurplusOrDeficit = @max_surplus;
                update wh set SurplusOrDeficit = 0, RunningQuantity = RunningQuantity - @max_surplus where id = @s_id;
                update wh set SurplusOrDeficit = SurplusOrDeficit + @max_surplus, RemainingDemand = RemainingDemand - @max_surplus where id = @d_id;
            end
            else
            begin
                -- We are done, some demand cannot be satisfied
                set @continue = 0;
            end
        end
        else
        begin
            update wh set RunningQuantity = RunningQuantity - @deficit, SurplusOrDeficit = SurplusOrDeficit - @deficit where id = @s_id;
            update wh set RemainingDemand = 0, SurplusOrDeficit = 0 where id = @d_id; 
        end
    end
end

select * from wh;
```