# FIFO Inventory by location, solve with CTE?

Tags: sql, t-sql, fifo, inventory, inventory-management

I've been trying to solve the following with a CTE for about 6 hours now and I'm starting to wonder if I can. Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[INV](
    [InvID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Product] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TransactionCode] [char](2) NULL,
    [Qty] [decimal](15, 6) NULL,
    [FromWhse] [char](2) NULL,
    [ToWhse] [char](2) NULL,
    [TransactionDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TRHIST] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InvID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[INV] ON
INSERT [dbo].[INV] ([InvID], [Product], [TransactionCode], [Qty],  [FromWhse], [ToWhse], [TransactionDate]) VALUES (1, N'Product1', N'PR', CAST(100.000000 AS Decimal(15, 6)), N'W1', NULL, CAST(0x0000A6EE00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[INV] ([InvID], [Product], [TransactionCode], [Qty], [FromWhse], [ToWhse], [TransactionDate]) VALUES (2, N'Product1', N'PR', CAST(200.000000 AS Decimal(15, 6)), N'W2', NULL, CAST(0x0000A6EF00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[INV] ([InvID], [Product], [TransactionCode], [Qty], [FromWhse], [ToWhse], [TransactionDate]) VALUES (3, N'Product1', N'TO', CAST(150.000000 AS Decimal(15, 6)), N'W2', N'D1', CAST(0x0000A6F000000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[INV] ([InvID], [Product], [TransactionCode], [Qty], [FromWhse], [ToWhse], [TransactionDate]) VALUES (4, N'Product1', N'SA', CAST(100.000000 AS Decimal(15, 6)), N'D1', NULL, CAST(0x0000A6F100000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[INV] ([InvID], [Product], [TransactionCode], [Qty], [FromWhse], [ToWhse], [TransactionDate]) VALUES (5, N'Product1', N'TO', CAST(50.000000 AS Decimal(15, 6)), N'W1', N'D1', CAST(0x0000A6F200000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[INV] ([InvID], [Product], [TransactionCode], [Qty], [FromWhse], [ToWhse], [TransactionDate]) VALUES (6, N'Product1', N'SA', CAST(75.000000 AS Decimal(15, 6)), N'D1', NULL, CAST(0x0000A6F300000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[INV] ([InvID], [Product], [TransactionCode], [Qty], [FromWhse], [ToWhse], [TransactionDate]) VALUES (7, N'Product2', N'PR', CAST(300.000000 AS Decimal(15, 6)), N'W1', NULL, CAST(0x0000A6F400000000 AS DateTime))

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[INV] OFF
```

This is a very simplified version of an inventory transaction table. The 3 transaction codes are 'PR' - Production, 'TO' - Transfer Order and 'SA' Sale. The sample data:

- InvID 1 - Warehouse W1 produces 100 of Product1 on Jan 1.
- InvID 2 - Warehouse W2 produces 200 of Product1 on Jan 2.
- InvID 3 - Warehouse W2 transfers 150 of Product1 to Warehouse D1 on Jan 3.
- InvID 4 - Warehouse D1 sells 100 of Product1 on Jan 4.
- InvID 5 - Warehouse W1 transfers 50 of Product1 to Warehouse D1 on Jan 5.
- InvID 6 - Warehouse D1 sells 75 of Product1 on Jan 6.
- InvID 7 - Warehouse W1 produces 300 of Product 2.

So all the FIFO examples I can find seem to focus on valuing inventory on a first in / first out basis. This one is more about crediting various warehouses on a first in / first out basis. I think I can safely ignore the 'PR' records, I'm only concerned with sales and transfers. So given the above sequence of transactions, the sale of 100 units on Jan 4 should be credited to W2 as the only inventory in place at the time of that sale was 150 units from W2. D1 would then have 50 units left from W2. On Jan 5, W1 transfers 50 units to D1. D1 now has 100 units, 50 from each W1 and W2. Now on Jan 6, D1 sells 75 units. So based on FIFO, 50 units should be deducted from the stock sourced from W2 and 25 would then be deducted from the stock sourced from W1. So the output I'm needing would look like this:

[image]

The first 5 columns are from the sale / 'SA' transaction. I get that they will be duplicated if an order is fulfilled from multiple sources. The remaining columns are fields from the 'TO' transaction from the source warehouse. I feel like I can solve this with a CTE and have been trying to do so for quite some time and I just can't get it right. Perhaps I've been staring at my code for too long. Is this possible with a CTE? I'm open to other options but I'd like to avoid a cursor if I could as it's a lot of records.

Comment: I think you must deal with a recursive solution.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420173/sql-subtracting-a-depleting-value-from-rows/9421009#9421009) answer demonstrates how to finagle pooled inventory with a CTE. It might provide a hint or two. Tip: The recursive query in a CTE can contain one or more `union`s, e.g. to process production, transfer and sale transactions. That said, some problems don't get along well with CTEs and are best solved with a loop.