# Decreasing value if some amount left

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've got a table

```
id|item_id | user_id |amount | date
1    21         12      6       2017-05-12  
2    21         12      20      2017-05-12
3    16         234     10      2017-06-12
4    21         16      25      2017-06-12
5    54         12      20      2017-08-01
6    112        12      2       2017-09-23
...
```

I receive the other data where i have for example:

```
itemId = 21
userId = 12
amount = 10
```

Then i need update amounts in my previous table. I have to update first and second record respectivly 6 to 0 and 20 to 16  for  user 12 and item 21 to fulfill amount of 10 i received.

How can i do this? I thnk stored procedure will be ok. I'd like to not use a cursor for this.

Comment: You might want to browse [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420173/sql-subtracting-a-depleting-value-from-rows/9421009#9421009) question while waiting for the Free Coding Team.

Comment: Thanks @HABO for helpful link. I had no idea how to name my problem. While waiting for the Team i'll try to understand your code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE @itemId INT = 21
DECLARE @userId INT = 12
DECLARE @amount INT = 10

DECLARE @new_amount INT = 0

UPDATE  TableTest
SET 
    @new_amount = CASE WHEN (Amount - @amount) < 0 THEN 0 ELSE Amount - @amount END
    , @amount = CASE WHEN @amount - Amount < 0 THEN 0 ELSE @amount - Amount END
    , Amount = @new_amount
FROM TableTest
WHERE item_id = @itemId
    and [user_id] = @userId
```