# Transactions , Invoices and document relations in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble computing a query for transactions and relations.

So i've got ***documents*** table: (id, name, total_value, id_partner)

and ***relations*** table: (id_parent, id_child, value).

***documents*** table stores transactions and invoices
***relations*** table stores relations between transactions and invoices

a transaction can pay multiple invoices.

What i got so far is:

```
SELECT  DCS.ID,
    DCS.ID_PARTNER,
        DCS.TOTAL_VALUE,
        COALESCE(ASDR.[PAID], 0) [PAID_VALUE],
        (DCS.TOTAL_VALUE - COALESCE(ASDR.[PAID], 0)) [UNPAID_VALUE]
        FROM DOCUMENTS DCS

LEFT JOIN (SELECT SDR.ID_PARENT, SUM(SDR.VALUE) [PAID] FROM RELATIONS SDR GROUP BY SDR.ID_PARENT) ASDR ON (DCS.ID = ASDR.ID_PARENT)

WHERE  DCS.ID_PARTNER = 25
```

My query should return paid invoices by current transaction and partner and unpaid invoices for current partner.

If a invoice is fully paid by another transaction it should not be displayed in current transaction.

If a invoice is partially paid by another transaction it should be displayed in current transaction.

Also i have to return the total paid amount for invoice.

***SQL Fiddle***: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76bce/2

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and exepct result?

Comment: Ok , i will make a sql fiddle

Comment: Although inefficient, I think your query should work. What's wrong with it?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76bce/2

Comment: What''s your expect result?

Comment: My expected result is to display all invoices which are fully paid in current transaction (current transaction can be passed as a parameter) , and open invoices for current partner (which are not fully paid).

Comment: Your description of the problem makes me think that you want to take each payment and start applying it to invoices, paying them off if possible and applying any remainder to subsequent invoices (all grouped by partner). If so, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9421009/92546) answer may provide some clues.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
select
  d.*,
  coalesce(sum(r.value), 0) as paid_value,
  d.total_value - coalesce(sum(r.value), 0) as unpaid_value
from documents d
left join relations r on r.id_parent = d.id
where d.id_partner = 25
group by d.id
```