# How to implement many-to-many matching without cursor

Tags: t-sql

I have two tables Orders and Inventory.

```sql
create table #orders
(orderId int,
demand decimal,
itemId int)

create table #inventory 
(invId int,
qtyOnHand decimal,
itemId int)

insert into #orders 
values(101, 2, 999)

insert into #orders 
values(102, 1, 999)

insert into #inventory
values(601, 1, 999)
insert into #inventory
values(602, 4, 999)
insert into #inventory
values(603, 1, 999)
```

I need to assign corresponding Inventory quantity to sorted Order. So expected result is:

```sql
orderID - inventoryID - reservedQty
101       601          1
101       602          1
102       602          1
```

The main concern is that #inventory.qtyOnHand is changing while I assign it to order

What I already tried is to aggregate all inventory

```sql
 SELECT
itemId,
sum(qtyOnHand) as qtyOnHand,
STUFF((
SELECT ', ' + cast(invId as varchar)
FROM #inventory
WHERE (itemId = inv.itemId)
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS inv_info
into #inv_aggr
FROM #inventory inv
GROUP BY itemId

select #orders.orderId, 
case  when ( #inv_aggr.qtyOnHand >= (select sum(o.demand) from #orders o where  o.itemId = #orders.itemId and o.orderId <= #orders.orderId))
then #orders.demand
else #inv_aggr.qtyOnHand - (select coalesce(sum(demand), 0) from #orders o where o.itemId = #orders.itemId and o.orderId < #orders.orderId)
end as qty_rsvd,
#inv_aggr.inv_info
from #orders
inner join #inv_aggr
on #inv_aggr.itemId =#orders.itemId and #inv_aggr.qtyOnHand > 0
```

But it does not help because I can split and match orders by inventory

I will appreciate any advise on how can I implement this or how can I split this task in several.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420173/sql-subtracting-a-depleting-value-from-rows/9421009#9421009) answer help? You may find some other related posts by searching for `[tsql]  deplete`.

Comment: Great first post! way to go on posting usable sample data and readable desired results!

Answer (score 1):

Love the inventory/order management problem, tried to do it entirely set-based (no looping) but without recursion as most would. Recursion adds complexity, potential performance challenges, and risks of hitting infinite loops

```
/*Raw data setup*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Orders
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Inventory
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #OrderRange
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #InventoryRange

CREATE TABLE #Orders(OrderID INT,Demand INT,ItemID INT)
CREATE TABLE #Inventory (InvID INT,QtyOnHand INT,ItemID INT)

INSERT INTO #Orders 
VALUES(101, 2,999)
,(102, 1,999)
,(103,10,222)
,(104,1,222)
,(105,4,222)

INSERT INTO #Inventory
VALUES(601, 1,999)
,(602, 4,999)
,(603, 1,222)
,(604,2,222)
,(605,2,222)

/*Setup work tables
Essentially ranges number each inventory and reserves a range of ID's for each order*/
SELECT *
    ,LowerRange = SUM(Demand) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY OrderID) - Demand + 1
    ,UpperRange = SUM(Demand) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY OrderID)
INTO #OrderRange
FROM #Orders

SELECT *
    ,LowerRange = SUM(QtyOnHand) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY InvID)- QtyOnHand + 1
    ,UpperRange = SUM(QtyOnHand) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY InvID) 
INTO #InventoryRange
FROM #Inventory

/*Final query*/
SELECT 
     O.OrderID
    ,I.InvID
    ,O.ItemID
    ,C.ReservedQty
    ,O.Demand
    ,I.QtyOnHand
    ,QtyFulfilled = SUM(C.ReservedQty) OVER (PARTITION BY O.OrderID,O.ItemID ORDER BY I.InvID) /*When this less than Demand OR NULL, then order not enough stock to fulfill order*/
    ,QtyRemaining = O.Demand - SUM(ISNULL(C.ReservedQty,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY O.OrderID,O.ItemID ORDER BY I.InvID) /*Inverse basically of QtyFulfilled*/
FROM #OrderRange AS O
LEFT JOIN #InventoryRange AS I
    ON O.ItemID = I.ItemID
    AND (
        /*Overlap between order range and inventory ranges*/
        O.LowerRange BETWEEN I.LowerRange and I.UpperRange
        OR O.UpperRange BETWEEN I.LowerRange and I.UpperRange
        /*For when entire inventory range between order range*/
        OR I.UpperRange BETWEEN O.LowerRange AND O.UpperRange
        )
CROSS APPLY (
    /*Finds the count of overlap between order range and inventory range
    Essentially orders all range values and finds the two middle numbers, then calculates the delta of them
    Ex. If you have a range of 2 to 5 and 3 to 6
        It sorts the numbers as 2,3,5,6
        It grabs the second value 3 (OFFSET 1 FETCH 1), then because LEAD runs before OFFSET it grabs the next row so 5
        The delta of 3 and 5 = 2 so there's a 2 number overlap between the two ranges
    */
    SELECT ReservedQty = LEAD(DTA.Points,1) OVER (ORDER BY DTA.Points) - DTA.Points + 1
    FROM (VALUES(O.LowerRange),(O.UpperRange),(I.LowerRange),(I.UpperRange)) AS DTA(Points)
    ORDER BY Points
    OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
            ) AS C
ORDER BY O.Orderid,I.InvID
```