# SQL Challenge with Inventory transfers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is the problem: given 2 tables, a set of locations and Sku's that are light inventory, and another table (locations and sku's) that are heavy inventory - how do I go about creating another table that indicates where I should send the excess inventory?

The transfers table will/can have multiple records (sku / location / amount). Say one location doesn't have enough, then location 2 will get added in. Transfers should be ordered by those that have the most, and those that need the most. So if one location has 10 extra and another has 5 extra the 10 extra one transfers inventory first.

If location 1 has 10 extra sx1 items and location 2 has 5 extra sx1 items.  Location 30 needs 12 sx1 items. They should get the 10 from location 1 and 2 from location 2. There might be another location that needs them as well.

I've been banging my head against a wall to figure this out and am only coming up with weird temp queries that don't work.

Here's some code to create the temp tables. SQL Server 2017

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempExcessInventory;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempNeededInventory;

CREATE TABLE #tempExcessInventory
(
             InventoryLocation VARCHAR(255)
            ,SKUName           VARCHAR(255)
            ,ExcessInventory   INT
);

CREATE TABLE #tempNeededInventory
(
             InventoryLocation VARCHAR(255)
            ,SKUName           VARCHAR(255)
            ,NeededInventory   INT
);

Insert into #tempExcessInventory
values 
('A1','SKUName1',7)
,('A2','SKUName2',1)
,('A3','SKUName3',10)
,('A4','SKUName4',4)
,('A5','SKUName5',2)
,('A6','SKUName6',10)
,('A7','SKUName7',2)
,('A8','SKUName8',8)
,('A9','SKUName9',5)
,('A10','SKUName10',9)
,('A11','SKUName11',3)
,('A12','SKUName12',3)
,('A13','SKUName13',8)
,('A14','SKUName14',3)
,('A15','SKUName15',9)
,('A16','SKUName16',10)
,('A17','SKUName17',6)
,('A18','SKUName18',4)
,('A19','SKUName19',3)
,('A20','SKUName20',10)
,('A21','SKUName21',3)
,('A22','SKUName22',7)
,('A23','SKUName23',3)
,('B1','SKUName1',2)
,('B2','SKUName2',9)
,('B3','SKUName3',5)
,('B4','SKUName4',5)
,('B5','SKUName5',10)
,('B6','SKUName6',9)
,('B7','SKUName7',9)
,('B8','SKUName8',9)
,('B9','SKUName9',3)
,('B10','SKUName10',5)
,('B11','SKUName11',4)
,('B12','SKUName12',6)
,('B13','SKUName13',1)
,('B14','SKUName14',10)
,('B15','SKUName15',1)
,('B16','SKUName16',9)
,('B17','SKUName17',3)
,('B18','SKUName18',7)
,('B19','SKUName19',9)
,('B20','SKUName20',4)
,('B21','SKUName21',8)
,('B22','SKUName22',5)
,('B23','SKUName23',1)


Insert into #tempNeededInventory
values 
('A1','SKUName1',5)
,('A2','SKUName2',2)
,('A3','SKUName3',10)
,('A4','SKUName4',3)
,('A5','SKUName5',10)
,('A6','SKUName6',9)
,('A7','SKUName7',1)
,('A8','SKUName8',4)
,('A9','SKUName9',5)
,('A10','SKUName10',8)
,('A11','SKUName11',3)
,('A12','SKUName12',2)
,('A13','SKUName13',6)
,('A14','SKUName14',8)
,('A15','SKUName15',8)
,('A16','SKUName16',8)
,('A17','SKUName17',7)
,('A18','SKUName18',6)
,('A19','SKUName19',9)
,('A20','SKUName20',10)
,('A21','SKUName21',9)
,('A22','SKUName22',8)
,('A23','SKUName23',7)
,('B1','SKUName1',2)
,('B2','SKUName2',3)
,('B3','SKUName3',3)
,('B4','SKUName4',9)
,('B5','SKUName5',5)
,('B6','SKUName6',8)
,('B7','SKUName7',2)
,('B8','SKUName8',5)
,('B9','SKUName9',1)
,('B10','SKUName10',7)
,('B11','SKUName11',1)
,('B12','SKUName12',6)
,('B13','SKUName13',7)
,('B14','SKUName14',5)
,('B15','SKUName15',8)
,('B16','SKUName16',10)
,('B17','SKUName17',5)
,('B18','SKUName18',6)
,('B19','SKUName19',7)
,('B20','SKUName20',10)
,('B21','SKUName21',8)
,('B22','SKUName22',2)
,('B23','SKUName23',4)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your expected output

Comment: You might get some ideas from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420173/sql-subtracting-a-depleting-value-from-rows/9421009#9421009) answer that uses a CTE to work through allocating orders against inventory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code might help:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #FinalInventoryTransferTable;
CREATE TABLE #FinalInventoryTransferTable
(ExcessInventoryLocation VARCHAR(255), 
 ExcessInventory         INT, 
 SKUName                 VARCHAR(255), 
 NeededInventoryLocation VARCHAR(255), 
 NeededInventory         INT
);
DECLARE @InventoryLocation VARCHAR(100), @SKUName VARCHAR(100), @NeededInventory VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR SELECT InventoryLocation, 
           SKUName, 
           NeededInventory
    FROM #tempNeededInventory;
OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @InventoryLocation, @SKUName, @NeededInventory;
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        WHILE(@NeededInventory > 0)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #FinalInventoryTransferTable
                       SELECT t.InventoryLocation AS ExcessInventoryLocation, 
                              t.ExcessInventory, 
                              t.SKUName, 
                              @InventoryLocation AS NeededInventoryLocation, 
                              @NeededInventory AS NeededInventory
                       FROM
                       (
                           SELECT TOP 1 *
                           FROM #tempExcessInventory ei
                           WHERE ei.skuname = @SKUName
                                 AND @NeededInventory <= ei.ExcessInventory
                       ) t;
                UPDATE ei
                  SET 
                      ExcessInventory = CASE
                                            WHEN(@NeededInventory - ei.ExcessInventory) < 0
                                            THEN ABS(@NeededInventory - ei.ExcessInventory)
                                            ELSE 0
                                        END
                FROM #tempExcessInventory ei
                     JOIN #FinalInventoryTransferTable ft ON ei.skuname = @SKUName
                                            AND ei.InventoryLocation = ft.ExcessInventoryLocation
                                            AND @NeededInventory = ft.NeededInventory;
                SELECT @NeededInventory = CASE
                                              WHEN(@NeededInventory - ei.ExcessInventory) < 0
                                              THEN ABS(@NeededInventory - ei.ExcessInventory)
                                              ELSE 0
                                          END
                FROM #tempNeededInventory ni
                     LEFT JOIN #tempExcessInventory ei ON ei.skuname = @SKUName
                                                          AND ni.InventoryLocation = @InventoryLocation;
            END;
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @InventoryLocation, @SKUName, @NeededInventory;
    END;
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
select * from #FinalInventoryTransferTable
--check remaining excess inventory
select * from #tempExcessInventory
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f2666077b433498ebea7bfeca41a5f24)

Comment: This took me in the right direction.  I added a column of quantity left on the excess table to do the running total.  I also did a double check at the end to make sure there was available inventory for the need.  Otherwise there could be an infinite loop.