# Join two tables then split rows depending on quantity

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I've been trying to build a stored proc in t-sql that combines the below two tables A and B and their `GrpID` and `BatchNO` values, splitting the combined records depending on `Qty`. I've tried joining them and then whittling down the result, but haven't had much success since the only thing they have in common is Part. So I'm stumped.

The tables contain the same parts, but they're just grouped in different ways. It does not matter what `BatchNO` gets applied to which `GrpID`, so long as the total `Qty` of each `GrpID` and `BatchNO` stay the same.

Table A:

```
Part     | GrpID | Qty  | RowNumber
----------------------------------
1-852334 | RTRN  | 5    | 1
1-852334 | BING  | 16   | 2
1-852334 | REGR  | 264  | 3
```

Table B:

```
Part     | BatchNO | Qty  | RowNumber
------------------------------------
1-852334 | 405304  | 35   | 1
1-852334 | 825304  | 250  | 2
```

One example of the final product could be:

```
Part     | GrpID | BatchNO | Qty
------------------------------------
1-852334 | RTRN  | 405304  | 5
1-852334 | BING  | 405304  | 16
1-852334 | REGR  | 405304  | 14
1-852334 | REGR  | 825304  | 250
```

Part of the difficulty is that the number of records per part in A and B varies. Above we had three in A and two in B, but that isn't always the case - sometimes there are two in A, five in B; three in A, seven in B; etc.

Is there any way to do this? Hopefully this makes sense but let me know if there's any more info that might help. Thanks for any help at all.

Comment: On the first sight this depends on the rows' sort order, correct? Is there any additional column to ensure the sort order? And please state your RDBMS together with the version. The tag `[tsql]` points to SQL-Server, but this is not sure. The version is necessary as the solution might depend on functions not available in any version.

Comment: Can the QTY values be negative?

Comment: It looks like a typical warehouse stock picking problem. You might get some hints from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420173/sql-subtracting-a-depleting-value-from-rows/9421009#9421009) answer.

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks for the tip, I added a tag for SQL Server 2016. It doesn't necessarily depend on the rows' sort order, but I added a column that could be created to ensure the sort order if it helps.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The QTY values cannot be negative.

Comment: @HABO Appreciate the link, this is indeed related to a stock issue with our warehouse. I'll definitely take a look in the meantime.