# While loop not selecting the desired record after temp table updated

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a nested while loop to pick some stock records from a #stock table. If the stock is depleted, I need to move to the next matching stock record. My loop keeps picking the same row from the temp table. Even if I delete the row, and verify within the nested Begin...End.

```
WHILE @DemandOutstandingQty > 0 --Check for stock
    BEGIN

SET ROWCOUNT 1
    SELECT @StockExpirationDate = ExpirationDate, @StockRemainingQty = RemainingQty, @StockLotNum = LotNum, @StockID = StockGUID
    FROM #stock WHERE PartNum = @DemandPartNum AND RemainingQty > 0
    ORDER BY ExpirationDate ASC

WHILE @StockID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
SET ROWCOUNT 0

--several other if blocks here end with demand going to 0 and breaking to the outer While

IF (@StockExpirationDate > @DemandDueDate AND @StockRemainingQty < @DemandOutstandingQty) --Stock not enough to meet demand
    BEGIN
        UPDATE #Stock SET RemainingQty = 0 WHERE StockGUID = @StockID;
        --DELETE FROM #stock WHERE StockGUID = @StockID; --Tried this also
        SET @DemandOutstandingQty = @DemandOutstandingQty - @StockRemainingQty; 
        Print @@StockID --The stock record with no remaining stock or deleted
        Select * from #stock where StockGUID = @StockID; --returns no rows / updated remaining qty
    END;

SET ROWCOUNT 1
    SELECT @StockExpirationDate = ExpirationDate, @StockRemainingQty = RemainingQty, @StockLotNum = LotNum, @StockID = StockGUID
    FROM #stock 
    WHERE PartNum = @DemandPartNum AND RemainingQty > 0 AND StockGUID <> @StockID
    ORDER BY ExpirationDate ASC
    Print @StockID --Its the same ID, not moving to the next stock record

SET ROWCOUNT 0

END --@StockID while

--does some more stuff

END --Outer While
```

Could this be because of the nested Begin...End?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL and sample data help us help you. Try adding `@@RowCount` to your diagnostic `print`. You may not be selecting anything, so `@StockID` never changes. Aside: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420173/sql-subtracting-a-depleting-value-from-rows/9421009#9421009) answer provides a rather different way of approaching the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

Switched to WHILE @StockRemainingQty > 0 for the condition and set '@StockRemainingQty = 0 when the stock ran out.

Thanks HABO for the heads up. @stockID was not changing.