# Query to transform data into opening-closing pair

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 2 columns i.e. recordNum(int) and qty (float) and data in that table is like following:

[image]

and I am trying to come up with query which can transform it to following:

[image]

I am using SQL Server 2012.

We have to prepare a opening-closing record number pair. The logic is as follows:

1st row: 1001 record num is opening record with quantity = 100

2nd row: 50 out of 100 quantity is closed by record num 1002

3rd row: remaining 50 quantity of 1001 is closed by 1003(which is of quantity 60)

4th row: after closing 50, 1003 will still have -10 quantity available.

As per request, I am adding my attempt to description:

```
select
    t.openRecordNum
    ,t.closingRecordNum
    ,t.qty

from
(
    select * 
    , openRecordNum = case when t.openQ>0 then min(t.recordNumber) over( order by seqId) 
    else
    max(t.recordNumber) over( order by seqId)
     end
    , closingRecordNum = Max(t.recordNumber)  over( order by seqId)
    from
    (
        select 
        *
        ,openQ = sum(qty) over( order by seqId)
        from Table_1
    ) t
) t
```

But I am nowhere close to desired result. I am getting following:

[image]

Comment: I feel like the sample we have doesn't tell the full story.

Comment: @DaleK I have added my attempt to question description. However I am nowhere close to solution. Thanks

Comment: It looks a little like a warehouse stock picking problem. You might find something useful in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420173/sql-subtracting-a-depleting-value-from-rows/9421009#9421009) answer using a CTE to process the data.

Comment: Thanks @HABO I will look into it.