# Constraint Logics and Homework

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am stuck at a homework

Objective:
**Whenever a new sale is made the quantity sold cannot exceed the existing stocked quantity for each of the products that it includes.** This means that the sale item(s) that cause the inconsistency should not be kept in the database. Notice that, regarding the calculation of the existing stock, the same product could be taken from different warehouses and/or purchase orders.

To recreate the database, you can use following DDL Code

```
USE [INVENTORY_fresh]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PURCHASE_ITEMS]    Script Date: 17-12-2020 18:57:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PURCHASE_ITEMS](
    [PO] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [PRODUCT] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [PURCHASE_QUANTITY] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [IN_STOCK] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [QUANTITY_SOLD] [smallint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PURCHASE_ITEMS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PO] ASC,
    [PRODUCT] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PURCHASE_ORDERS]    Script Date: 17-12-2020 18:57:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PURCHASE_ORDERS](
    [IDPURCHASEORDER] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WAREHOUSE] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [PURCHASE_DATETIME] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [PK_PURCHASE_ORDERS]    Script Date: 17-12-2020 18:57:45 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PURCHASE_ORDERS] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_PURCHASE_ORDERS] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [IDPURCHASEORDER] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PURCHASE_ITEMS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PURCHASE_ITEMS_PO] FOREIGN KEY([PO])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PURCHASE_ORDERS] ([IDPURCHASEORDER])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PURCHASE_ITEMS] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PURCHASE_ITEMS_PO]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PURCHASE_ITEMS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PURCHASE_ITEMS_PRODUCTS] FOREIGN KEY([PRODUCT])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PRODUCTS] ([PRODUCTCODE])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PURCHASE_ITEMS] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PURCHASE_ITEMS_PRODUCTS]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PURCHASE_ORDERS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PO_WAREHOUSE] FOREIGN KEY([WAREHOUSE])
REFERENCES [dbo].[WAREHOUSES] ([WAREHOUSECODE])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PURCHASE_ORDERS] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PO_WAREHOUSE]
GO
```

If you want to download full Script with data, to create environment - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vY1nJk1Dm7K3k1VNERgk3V6LieLIqlWw/view?usp=sharing

**What I have done so far?**

I have created a constraint that will ensure the QUANITY_SOLD is not more than total sum of IN_STOCK for every product

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PURCHASE_ITEMS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Sold_not_greater_stock] CHECK  (([dbo].[totalstock]([product])>=[quantity_sold]))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PURCHASE_ITEMS] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Sold_not_greater_stock]
GO
```

Additionally, I made a rule that the IN_STOCK columns will not become A NEGATIVE VALUE

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PURCHASE_ITEMS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [cantbenegative] CHECK  (([in_stock]>=(0)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PURCHASE_ITEMS] CHECK CONSTRAINT [cantbenegative]
GO
```

After that, I created a trigger that will update IN_STOCK and QUANITITY_SOLD

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE   TRIGGER [DBO].[TEST_TRIGGER] ON [DBO].[PURCHASE_ITEMS] FOR UPDATE
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @PRODUCT INT
    DECLARE @PO INT
    DECLARE @QUANITY_SOLD_OLD INT 
    DECLARE @QUANITY_SOLD_NEW INT 

    SELECT @PO = PO, @PRODUCT = PRODUCT, @QUANITY_SOLD_OLD = QUANTITY_SOLD FROM DELETED
    SELECT @QUANITY_SOLD_NEW = QUANTITY_SOLD FROM INSERTED WHERE PRODUCT = @PRODUCT AND PO = @PO
    IF @QUANITY_SOLD_OLD < @QUANITY_SOLD_NEW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE PURCHASE_ITEMS SET IN_STOCK = IN_STOCK - (@QUANITY_SOLD_NEW-@QUANITY_SOLD_OLD)
            WHERE PRODUCT = @PRODUCT AND PO = @PO
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE PURCHASE_ITEMS SET IN_STOCK = IN_STOCK + (@QUANITY_SOLD_OLD-@QUANITY_SOLD_NEW)
            WHERE PRODUCT = @PRODUCT AND PO = @PO
    END
END

GO

ALTER TABLE [DBO].[PURCHASE_ITEMS] ENABLE TRIGGER [TEST_TRIGGER]
GO
```

**The Problem**

While my trigger can update IN_STOCK and QUANTITY_SOLD, its limited to one row.

Suppose there are 11 same products in warehouse 1 and 45 in warehouse 2 and quanitity_sold is 12, my trigger should update IN_STOCK for warehouse 1 as 0 and warehouse 2 as 44.

I'm not sure if I was able to explain my question clearly enough but I tried my best. Please help me.

Comment: Start over. You make a common and fundamental mistake - that only a single row is affected by the update (or merge) statement that caused the trigger to execute. This flaw has been discussed many, many times and simple searching will find discussions about how to properly address the possibility of multiple rows. And you need to investigate THROW. Your trigger needs to generate an error when the conditions you mention are not satisfied. Lastly, please format your code for readability - a GOOD habit to develop.

Comment: And I suggest you break your goal into pieces that can be more easily achieved - another GOOD habit. Along with that is posting the relevant DDL and sample data as script in your question. I'm not going to download from an unknown source. Nor is that file going to be available forever for others to examine at later points in time. Your question should be self-contained to benefit future readers.

Comment: Agree with @SMor, but still a relatively good job creating a homework question on Stackoverflow being a new user.

Comment: @SMor, Thank you, I will add DDL to my question and alter my script to make it more readable. Many thanks for your input

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9421009/92546) answer for some ideas.

Comment: I noticed that your check constraint uses a UDF (totalstock).  Please be aware that this will keep your plan from going parallel. [Read here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/04/another-hidden-parallelism-killer-scalar-udfs-check-constraints/) Brent Ozar blogged about this.

Comment: @JMabee that is true but my constraint validates other values from other tables. Not sure how to do that without function. Would appreciate if you could point me in right direction for that as well.