# How do I create log of running balance of debits associated to the credits

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I wonder if someone can assist me please and I am at a loss as to how to achieve this without having to iterate through each row with quite a few 'IF' statement.

I have a table of credits and debits and I am trying to create a log for any debits and record with  the transaction reference linked to the previous credit(s).

For example, if I had the following row of credit/debit transactions

| Transaction Ref | Transaction Date | Transaction Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 Jan 2023 | Credit | 2000 |
| 2 | 1 Apr 2023 | Credit | 1000 |
| 3 | 1 May 2023 | Debit | -200 |
| 4 | 1 Aug 2023 | Credit | 700 |
| 5 | 1 Oct 2023 | Debit | -1800 |

Here is a cut down version to setup some test data

```
CREATE TABLE [TransactionLog] (
    [Customer Id]       VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [Transaction Ref]   VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [Transaction Date]  DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    [Transaction Type]  VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    [Amount]            Money  NOT NULL
);
 
CREATE TABLE [OutputDebitLogs] (
    [Customer Id]       VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [crTransaction Ref] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [dbTransaction Ref] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [Amount]            Money  NOT NULL
);
 
 
INSERT INTO [TransactionLog] VALUES ('1', '1', '1 Jan 2022', 'Credit', 2000)
INSERT INTO [TransactionLog] VALUES ('1', '2', '1 Apr 2022', 'Credit', 1000)
INSERT INTO [TransactionLog] VALUES ('1', '3', '1 May 2022', 'Debit', -200)
INSERT INTO [TransactionLog] VALUES ('1', '4', '1 Aug 2022', 'Credit', 700)  
INSERT INTO [TransactionLog] VALUES ('1', '5', '1 Oct 2022', 'Debit', -1800)
```

I would like to create an Output log (working from oldest date), where the debit transaction would create a record for the credits that it is being deducted from.

For example - the first debit record (transaction ref 3) would be deducted from the 1 Apr 2023 credit record (Transaction Ref 2) leaving an amount of 800 on Transaction ref 2.

So it would write a record for this as follows

| Debit Ref | Credit ref | Debit Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 200 |

The next debit (Transaction 5) would yield the following records

| Debit Ref | Credit ref | Debit Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 4 | 700 |
| 5 | 2 | 800 |
| 5 | 1 | 300 |

As you can see this is because the 1800 debit would deduct from the 3 previous credits due to Transaction Ref 2 (1 Apr 2023) already having the 200 deducted.

To have this working correctly the sql script would have to look at what has already been added to the "Output Log so that it knows to include it in the calculations.

I've tried several queries, but am unable to resolve this, so am not too sure if this can be achieved through a combination of a Windows/CTE function.

Hope someone can assist on this.

Thanks in advance
Dave

Comment: This can be solved with a loop, but it's not fast, also usually this kind of operation is not good, because you should match debit against credit when it's performed and not trying to hack it afterwards. Also, to me it's more logical to match against the oldest debts first. Finally, shouldn't it be Debit ref 3, Credit Ref 2?

Comment: Thanks Siggemannen. Yea  I know that this could be resolved by looping with a bunch of IF statements, however as you've mentioned this would be a very slow process considering there will be 1000s of records to process daily.

The reason why I'm looking at the last one is that is for a bigger process and I have to work on the Last In First Out principle for calculating the data.

Comment: how do you get 700/800/300 for credit #4/#2/#1? what is the formula behind

Comment: Though the problem is rather different, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9421009/92546) shows how to handle picking orders from "lots" in inventory using a CTE. You may find some hints there.

Comment: Hi LONG

Working on the Last In First Out (LIFO) principle, If you work backwards from Transaction Ref #5 (1800) debit record, the first credit record it comes across is Transaction Ref #4, which has a credit amount of 700. This 700 is then deducted from the 1,800 leaving 1100. 

We still have 1100 left, so the system then has to find the previous credit record, which is Transaction Ref #2. Now even through Transaction #2 initially had a credit of 1000, 200 of that had already been deducted from Transaction #3 (ie the -200 debit). So, we have to deduct 800 from Transaction #2.

Comment: This now leaves 300 remaining, so the system looks for the previous credit, which is Transaction # 1. We will now deduct the final 300 from Transaction #1.

Hope I've explained it a bit better.